# Emberjs CollectionView changes from 0.9.7.1 to 1.0.pre?

Tags: collections, ember.js

I had some code that connected an ArrayController with CollectionView that no longer works once I upgrade to 1.0.pre.

It seems that CollectionView no longer passes each element of the collection to its template view class?

I've distilled my issue to this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chaodoze/CbwCN/

Notice it outputs to "1,2,3" on each line in 1.0.pre
In 0.9.7.1, it outputs correctly as a single digit on each line.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug? 
What is the best way to work-around this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.0.pre the view's context has changed. When you access `{{content}}` you are really accessing `{{controller.content}}`, which is `[1,2,3]`. You need to access the view's content, which in the individual number, that is done with `{{view.content}}`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/CbwCN/2/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, is there a url that lists changes from 0.9.7 to 1.0.pre? Thanks again!